# Show ng-repeat item only when value to display is not null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just stared learning AngularJS few days ago. 
I have a ng-repeat on an element, but I want to use ng-show with it somehow as well. 
This is my code now:

```
<p ng-repeat="(parameter,value) in object">{{parameter}}: {{value}}</p>
```

Which works well where object is structured as

```
{"MobilePhone":null,"Email":"test@email.com","HomePhone":null}
```

I want to show only elements that don't have null as a value. Something like:

```
 <p ng-repeat="(parameter,value) in object" ng-show={{value}}>{{parameter}}: {{value}}</p>
```

But I don't see why value would be available there for ng-show already? How can I do an "If" check for value before showing

?

Thanks for any help. 
If I was unclear, please ask for more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work, and only if `value` is a truly value it will be shown:

```
<p ng-repeat="(parameter,value) in obj" ng-show="value">{{parameter}}: {{value}}</p>
```

(You can also use [`ngIf`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf) instead)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zqJKH/

Comment: Sorry - do you maybe know how I would check if value exists? Might be there are some parameters without values...